# Python nose tests (actually the error is from Mox) print out errors one character per line (with line numbers!)

Tags: python, nose, nosetests

I've recently started using Nose for my unit tests. It's pretty good except that sometimes when an error occurs it prints out the error information in a really weird way. It splits it up into 1 character per line then prints it out with line numbers. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

```
....F...............
======================================================================
FAIL: accounts.tests.testaccountserver.test_create_account_writes_an_account_to_the_store
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tom/envs/myappshare/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 187, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/media/Shared/Dropbox/jobs/myapp/myappshare/src/accounts/tests/testaccountserver.py", line 102, in test_create_account_writes_an_account_to_the_store
    mox.VerifyAll()
  File "/home/tom/envs/myappshare/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mox.py", line 286, in VerifyAll
    mock_obj._Verify()
  File "/home/tom/envs/myappshare/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mox.py", line 506, in _Verify
    raise ExpectedMethodCallsError(self._expected_calls_queue)
ExpectedMethodCallsError: Verify: Expected methods never called:
  0.  V
  1.  e
  2.  r
  3.  i
  4.  f
  5.  y
  6.  :
  7.   
  8.  E
  9.  x
 10.  p
 11.  e
 12.  c
 13.  t
 14.  e
 15.  d
 16.   
 17.  m
 18.  e
```

And so on for 1346 lines!

EDIT:

It won't let me answer my own question for 8 hours, so I'm editing in the solution I found:

As Aaron Digulla points out the problem is not in nose but in Mox (which I'm using to Mock objects).

Adding this line to the top of *str* method of ExpectedMethodCallsError in mox.py fixes the problem (or this symptom anyway):

```
if isinstance(self._expected_methods, str):
  self._expected_methods = self._expected_methods.split("\n")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Aaron Digulla points out the problem is not in nose but in Mox (which I'm using to Mock objects).

Adding this line to the top of *str* method of ExpectedMethodCallsError in mox.py fixes the problem (or this symptom anyway):

```
if isinstance(self._expected_methods, basestring):
  self._expected_methods = self._expected_methods.split("\n")
```

Comment: the above won't work for unicode strings; a safer alternative, working for both str and unicode is: `isinstance(self._expected_methods, basestring)`

Comment: Thanks Davide, I've edited my answer to include your correction

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be an error in `ExpectedMethodCallsError`'s `__repr__` or `__str__` method.

Or in the code which registers the expected methods in `mock_obj`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure why I thought it was nose causing the problem and not Mox when it quite clearly shows it as thing from Mox.

Comment: Isn't this a bug in nose, because it is assuming it can instantiate `ExpectedMethodCallsError` by passing a string?  There's no requirement that a user-defined exception's constructor take a string as its first argument.

Answer (score 2):

I can't directly solve your problem, but I know how to generate similar. It seems that nose iterates through the stack trace:

```
for line in lines:
   print "%s" % line
```

If for some reason, variable `lines` is a string, the string will be iterated instead of lines (resulting in one line per character printing just like in your case).

As of what is the problem: I don't know :)

Answer (score 1):

On my system I found the string was being passed in as unicode, an additional test case will cover this:

```
if (isinstance(self._expected_methods, str) or 
    isinstance(self._expected_methods, unicode)):
    self._expected_methods = self._expected_methods.split("\n")
```